# Login scripts in SBS 2011

Tags: windows-sbs-2011, login-script

Where can I add and configure a login script for each user in SBS 2011?

For example, I to map a drive for a user-specific folder. I do not want to use folder redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's massively unsustainable. Ideally, you *should* use folder redirection. Why aren't you?

If you must use a script, You should craft a single script that uses variables and a sane folder structure on the share. For example, if the folder layout is `\\server\share\userFolder` you could get it done in a one-line logon script that reads:

`net use z: \\server\share\%username%`

You would link this in group policy under `User Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Scripts`

Make sure that wherever you store the script, all users have access to it via share and NTFS ACLs.

---

If you *really* must do this, you can define a logon script in ADUC for each user here:

[image: Screencap]

Comment: What about mapping a home folder to drive letter?

Comment: @John In my example, it would map the folder to the letter `Z:`. You can replace `Z:` with whatever other letter you want. You can also use the `Home Folder` field in the same screenshot that I posted above. That said, it's antiquated and you really shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SBS 2011 therefore it has to new Group Policy feature Group Policy Preferences, which I have used just last week to do exactly this.

I had heard about GP Preferences and used this tutorial to carry it out

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership.aspx